# How do I stop recording AudioRecord when button press out on Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, websocket

I have three problems.
First: I have to stop recording audio and streaming data to the server.
Second: I want to save the file and send an entire file to the server.
Third: I have to play these chunks in a receiver.

Sending audio to server:

```
btn_send.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            when (event?.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    Log.i("tou7ch", "apertou")
                    val buffer = ByteArray(minBufSize)
                    val chunks = buffer.toByteString()
                    audiorecord!!.startRecording()

                    val number = audiorecord!!.read(buffer, 0, minBufSize)
                    for (i in 0 until number) {
                        webSocket.send(chunks)
                    }
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    Log.i("tou7ch", "soltou")
                    audiorecord?.stop();
                }
            }

            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```

This works fine when sending, but I don't know how to stop sending. When a remove a finger from a button I have a `Log.i("tou7ch", "soltou")` and it's called perfectly.
If I put a while like this:

```
                    while (true) {
                        val number = audiorecord!!.read(buffer, 0, minBufSize)
                        for (i in 0 until number) {
                            webSocket.send(chunks)
                        }
                    }
```

Or any other variable to validate, the app stops running for an eternal while. How do I stop sending this to the server? How do I stop recording? How do I play these chunks in a receiver? How do I save this entire file in a .wav?

Thanks, devs!

Comment: you should implement coroutines for that!

Comment: Thanks! I'll look! I'm really glad about your life. Blessings!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin an optimal way is to use coroutines however if you don't want that here is a classical way to do this with thread:

```
btn_send.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
var thread?=null
                  when (event?.action) {
                   MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                   Log.i("tou7ch", "apertou")   
                    thread = Thread(){
                    override fun run(){
                   val buffer = ByteArray(minBufSize)
                        val chunks = buffer.toByteString()
                        audiorecord!!.startRecording()
    
                        val number = audiorecord!!.read(buffer, 0, minBufSize)
                        for (i in 0 until number) {
                            webSocket.send(chunks)
                        }
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        Log.i("tou7ch", "soltou")
                        audiorecord?.stop();
                        thread.interrupt();
                    }
                }
                  }
               }

  

            return v?.onTouchEvent(event) ?: true
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try a coroutine.

Comment: Sr. Patel, with coroutines the app stop break, but I still have a problem whit the while(isActive). This makes the app break. How do I stop sends chunks?

Comment: Post your logs please at where the app is breaking sometimes when your install wrong version of coroutines it makes the app crash

Comment: in your case since you're not experienced you can go with classical thread approach